# Handle Http connection with all exceptions and send and receive data using url in android

Tags: android

Hi i am working on web service application in android.i need a class that handle all exceptions and send receive json data using URL with parameters.please help me any one with good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet from a helper class I wrote to send data via POST.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", param1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", param2));

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.blabla.com/posterome");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

And to get the response...

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Classes used in this snippet are in `org.apache.http.*` package.

As for JSON, `JSONObject` will suffice. 
There are examples on how to use it properly everywhere on the web. Just google it.

Comment: Thanks AljoshaBre,can u please tell how to handle connection time out and socket time out exceptions in detail.

Comment: Does it times out on other hosts? Did you verified if its host-specific? Perhaps you're not catching the right one? Can you include a small, concise piece of code that catches the exception? And LogCat output would be useful. I'm on my way to satisfy my stomach. I will try to help you later.

Comment: i am getting times out on other hosts.

Comment: mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
ClientConnectionManager mgr=mHttpClient.getConnectionManager();
mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(
           new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
               mgr.getSchemeRegistry()),params);
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_SOCKET_TIME_OUT);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);